# Use Git (Windows) with a private key

Tags: windows, git

I have a Git repository on a Linux server and I want to clone it on Windows.

I have Git for Windows installed and I prefer using it with the command line.

I use SSH with a public key to connect to my Linux server and I have my keys generated and ready to use, but I don't know how to tell git to use the key.

When I just SSH into the box, I use this command:

```
ssh -i c:\path\to\private\key\id_rsa user@192.168.2.104
```

So, I guess I'm looking for Git's equivalent of the `-i` option.

Obviously, this doesn't work:

```
git -i c:\path\to\private\key\id_rsa clone user@192.168.2.104:/home/user/dev/myproject.git myproject
```

This is all on my local network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows, provided `%HOME%` is set to `%USERPROFILE%`, use a `%HOME%\.ssh\config` file, which can indicate, for a given entry name, the user *and* the path of the private key:

```
Host yourServer
  HostName 192.168.2.104
  User user
  IdentityFile C:/path/to/yourPrivateKey
```

Test it with `ssh -Tv yourServer`

Then a clone would be:

```
git clone yourServer:/home/user/dev/myproject.git myproject
```

(no need to indicate `user@192.168.2.104` or the path to the private key anymore: everything is in the `%HOME%/.ssh/config`)

That way, you can manage multiple ssh sets of public/private keys.

Comment: Thank you. I never knew about that file or thought that Git would use it. This works for Windows Git. Ironically, it's not working for ssh unless I use the `-F` option to make it read the right configuration file, but I think that's because of some peculiarity with the Cygwin version of ssh, which comes first in my `PATH`. I found more info to help me understand it better in [the man page for ssh_config](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man5/ssh_config.5.html) and [this article](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/).